# jquery move image from one place to the other using offsets giving weir results

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to make image moving animation along the straight line, but have failed miserably :) It goes totally in the wrong direction, and I cannot figure out why...

Please visit: http://kpi.ge/ultrasound-systems/philips-hdi5000/

And click "add to compare box" next to get-quote button.

Animation starts from there and should go straight to the left where compare box is... but it goes down and than appears in the right spot. I'm pretty sure there is something with parent offset not being correct, but as I understand offset is in relation to the document window, so  the result confuses me...

jquery:

```
var product_img = data;
var fdest_pos = $("#compareproducts").offset();


if (!$("#compareleft").has(".compareprodimg").length && !$(".compareboxbtn").has(".compareprodimg").length) {
    $("#clickedthis").append(product_img);
    $("#clickedthis").removeAttr("id");
    $(".compareboxbtn").children(".compareprodimg").css({
        position: "absolute"
    }).animate({
        left: fdest_pos.left,
        top: fdest_pos.top
    }, {
        complete: function () {

            $(this).removeAttr("style");
            $(this).appendTo("#compareleft");
            $("#compareleft").attr("class", "on");
            $("#compareleft").attr("href", get_param_url);

            //save to session
            $.session.set("compareLeftContent", product_img);
            $.session.set("compareLeftId", get_param_url);


            // if href is numeric turn on compare now button
            if ($("#compareleft").attr("href") > 0 && $("#compareright").attr("href") > 0) {

                $("#compareproducts .button").removeClass("off");
                $("#compareproducts .button").addClass("on");
                $("#compareproducts .button.on").on("click", function () {
                    window.location = "/kpi/compare/?product=" + $("#compareleft").attr("href") + "," + $("#compareright").attr("href");
                });

                $(".button.on").unbind("mouseenter mouseleave"); //Remove helper pop-up "add another product"


            } // if

        }
    });
} // if left
```

Comment: What values do `fdest_pos.left` and `fdest_pos.top` have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between `offset()` and the `left` and `top` CSS properties. `offset()` gives the location in relation to the *document*, and `left` and `top` are in relation to the *parent container*.

Let's say the target element's offset is 100 and 150 pixels. The element that's being animated probably starts with `left` and `top` both as zero, so when you animate them using the target offset, the element moves 100 pixels left and 150 pixels down. (You can see it on the web page: if you look at the animation movement and imagine it starting from the top left of the page, it would end up to the correct place.)

You need to calculate the difference between the offsets of both elements and animate by that amount. Something like this:

```
var product_pos = $(".compareboxbtn").children(".compareprodimg").offset();
var newLeft = fdest_pos.left - product_pos.left;
var newTop = fdest_pos.top - product_pos.top;

$(".compareboxbtn").children(".compareprodimg").css({
    position: "absolute"
}).animate({
    left: newLeft,
    top: newTop
}, {
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty is that you're inserting your image object in a different DOM node whose offsetParent is the body.
Before the animation, your object is contained in a DOM node with multiple nested offsetParents.

This means that before the move you have to get the elements current total offset, and start the animation from there. The following is a more generic solution because it would work for images no matter where they're nested in the DOM :

```
relativeOffsetParent = function() {
    var $ctx = $(this);
    var $op = $ctx.offsetParent();
    if ($ctx.is($op) || $op.css("position") === "relative") {
        return $op;
    } else {
        return relativeOffsetParent.call($op);
    }
};

recursiveOffset = function() {
    var $ctx = $(this);
    var offset = $ctx.offset();
    var $op = relativeOffsetParent($ctx);
    if ($ctx.is($op) || $op[0].tagName.match(/BODY|body/)? true : false) {
        return offset;
    } else {
        var pOffset = recursiveOffset.call($op);
    return {
        left: pOffset.left + offset.left,
        top: pOffset.top + offset.top
    };
  }
};


var fdest_pos = $("#compareleft").offset();

$(".compareboxbtn").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".compareprodimg").each(function(){
      var o = recursiveOffset.call($(this));
      $(this)
        .removeAttr("style")
        .appendTo("#compareleft")
        .css({
            zIndex:9999,
            position: "absolute",
            left: o.left,
            top: o.top
        })
        .animate({
            left: fdest_pos.left,
            top: fdest_pos.top
        })
      ;
    })
});
```

Here's a [**link to jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/AMBk4/6/)